# If a cell in a column contains a specific string, then add a different cell value to an additional cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to have Apps Script perform the following:

- If a cell in column H contains the string "Credit Card" then add that rows column C value (sum) to cell K6.

I believe I would put together a loop function for this, but I am a brand new beginner with JavaScript and coding in general.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As for Apps Script scripting, I see a [onSelectionChange trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that could initiate your script which would compare the stringified cell contents to "Credit Card".

Unrelated to Google Sheets, a webpage script would use Javascript with the DOM APIs, you would use [keyUp](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-keyup) events to trigger your script which would do a string comparison against the trimmed input [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), and then perform whatever actions you want to after that.

Comment: Apps Script doesn't include the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).